# Borrar directorio dentro de un directorio java

Tags: java, archivo

Tengo este código que me borra los ficheros de un directorio y el directorio en si. Pero si este directorio contiene otro directorio, este último no me lo borra, ni lo que tenga dentro. Cómo lo puedo hacer?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    String  directorio=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Qué directorio quieres borrar??", "Eliminar directorios", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    File dir=new File(directorio);
    
    if(dir.exists()) {
        File[]listaFich=dir.listFiles();
        
        System.out.println("Hay "+listaFich.length+" ficheros en este directorio.");
        
        for(int i=0;i<listaFich.length;i++) {
    
            if(listaFich[i].isFile()) {
                
                listaFich[i].delete();
                System.out.println("Se ha borrado "+listaFich[i]);
            }
        }
        
        if(dir.delete()) {
            
            System.out.println("Se ha borrado el directorio '"+dir.getName()+"'");
        }else {
            
            System.out.println("No se ha podido borrar el directorio "+dir.getName());
        }
    }else {
        
        System.out.println("NO EXISTE EL DIRECTORIO.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es eliminar de forma recursiva, prueba con este código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File archivo = new File("DIRECTORIO");
    deleteFile(archivo);
}

public static void deleteFile(File file){
    if (file.exists()) {
        if (file.isFile())
            file.delete();
        else {
            File f[]=file.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
                    deleteFile(f[i]);
            }
            file.delete();
        }
    }else
        System.out.println("El archivo no existe!");
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!Ha sido como magia!!hehe!

Comment: @HelenaMateosBravo si esto resuelve tu problema te recomiendo aceptar la respuesta, si solamente fue de ayuda dar clik en el boton de flecha hacia arriba. Saludos!